# Jersey 2 filter uses Container Request Context in Client Request Filter

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have a Jersey 2 Web Service that upon receiving a request, makes another request to another web service in order to form the response for the original request. So, when client "A" makes a request to my web service "B", "B" makes a request to "C" as part of forming the response to "A".

A->B->C

I want to implement a filter for a Jersey 2 web service that essentially does this:

- Client "A" will send a request that has a header like
  "My-Header:first"
- When my web service "B" then makes a client request "C", it should
  append to that header, so it sends a request with this header
  "My-Header:first,second".

I want to implement this as a filter so all of my resources don't have to duplicate the logic of appending to the request header.

However, in Jersey 2, you get these 4 filters:

- ContainerRequestFilter - Filter/modify inbound requests
- ContainerResponseFilter - Filter/modify outbound responses
- ClientRequestFilter - Filter/modify outbound requests
- ClientResponseFilter - Filter/modify inbound responses

[image: Jersey Filter Diagram]

I need to use the header from an inbound request, modify it, then use it an outbound request, so essentially I need something that is both a ContainerRequestFilter and a ClientRequestFilter. I don't think implementing both in the same filter will work, as you don't know which Client Request maps to which Container Request, or do you?

Comment: What do you mean by "when my web service then makes a client request"? Usually,a web service creates a response due to a client request.

Comment: Made the question a bit clearer now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a nice way to do this that doesn't use `ThreadLocal` to communicate between the `ContainerRequestFilter` and the `ClientRequestFilter`, as you can't assume that client requests made in response to a container request will be on the same thread.

The way I achieved this is by setting a property in the `ContainerRequestConext` object in the `ContainerRequestFilter`. I can then pass the `ContainerRequestContext` object (either explicity or through dependency injection) into my `ClientRequestFilter`. If you use dependency injection (if you're using Jersey 2 then you are probably using HK2), then all of this can be achieved without modifying any of your resource level logic.

Have a `ContainerRequestFilter` like this:

```
public class RequestIdContainerFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
    containerRequestContext.setProperty("property-name", "any-object-you-like");
}
```

And a `ClientRequestFilter` that takes a `ContainerRequestContext` in its constructor:

```
public class RequestIdClientRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

    private ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext;

    public RequestIdClientRequestFilter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {
        this.containerRequestContext = containerRequestContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext clientRequestContext) throws IOException {
        String value = containerRequestContext.getProperty("property-name");
        clientRequestContext.getHeaders().putSingle("MyHeader", value);
    }
}
```

Then it's just a case of tying this all together. You will need a factory to create any `Client` or `WebTarget` that you need:

```
public class MyWebTargetFactory implements Factory<WebTarget> {

    @Context
    private ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext;

    @Inject
    public MyWebTargetFactory(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {
        this.containerRequestContext = containerRequestContext;
    }

    @Override
    public WebTarget provide() {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        client.register(new RequestIdClientRequestFilter(containerRequestContext));
        return client.target("path/to/api");
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(WebTarget target) {

    }
}
```

Then register the filter and bind your factory on your main application `ResourceConfig`:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        register(RequestIdContainerFilter.class);
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindFactory(MyWebTargetFactory.class).to(WebTarget.class);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to do exactly this. The only question I have is - what are you calling .register() on in the last step? Thanks!

Comment: @NelsonMonterroso I've fixed my answer to make it clear now

Comment: Depending on how you want to manage the logic you are doing in the `ContainerRequestFilter`, you can remove it entirely, since from the injected `ContainerRequestContext` you can get the original request (including headers, etc.). I'm using that trick to implement a client that automatically passes through headers from the request to new HTTP calls.

Comment: Creating a new `Client` for each request is expensive though: [How To Use Jersey Client Efficiently](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/how-to-use-jersey-client-efficiently)

Answer (score 3):

A container filter can implement both, `ContainerRequestFilter` and `ContainerResponseFilter` in one single class. The same is true for client filters, `ClientRequestFilter` and `ClientResponseFilter` can both be implemented in one single filter implementation.

But you cannot mix as far as I know. Instead, you can have two separate filters that communicate with each other e.g. using `ThreadLocal` pattern:

```
// Container filter that stores the request context in a ThreadLocal variable
public class MyContainerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
    public static final ThreadLocal<ContainerRequestContext> requestContextHolder;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContextHolder.set(requestContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        // clean up after request
        requestContextHolder.remove();
    }
}

// Client request filter that uses the info from MyContainerRequestFilter
public class MyClientRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext =
            MyContainerRequestFilter.requestContextHolder.get();
        if (containerRequestContext != null) {
            // TODO: use info from containerRequestContext to modify client request
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the lifetime of a filter is per-request?

Comment: No, usually there is one instance per filter and application. But that doesn't matter here as every request is bound to a thread. So the ThreadLocal variable ensures that parallel requests do not mix up their static holder content.

Comment: Hmm thinking about this I don't think this would work, as if I have another method/resource that doesn't make a client call, the ThreadLocal object doesn't get cleaned up.

Comment: No, that's not true. ThreadLocal gets cleaned up anyway in the second filter method, which belongs to ContainerResponseFilter, i.e. it will be called AFTER the request (_A -> B_), no matter if _B -> C_ happens or not.