# Same QueryParams In All JAX-RS Endpoints

Tags: rest, jboss, glassfish, jax-rs

I have a requirement that a few QueryParams should be present in absolutely all JAX-RS endpoints of my application.

Is there a way to specify somewhere, only once, these parameters? Or do I have to repeat myself in all method endpoints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a `ContainerRequestFilter` and handle the parameters there. You can add the result to the `ContainerRequestContext`:

```
@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    Object result = // handle the parameter
    requestContext.setProperty("myParam", result);
  }

}
```

Your implementation will of course depend on your needs.

You can inject the context into your resource classes like:

```
@Context
private ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext;
```

See also:

- [Jersey 2 filter uses Container Request Context in Client Request Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995307/jersey-2-filter-uses-container-request-context-in-client-request-filter)